# How to use Nix niv to reference github project?

Tags: nix

I'm currently using the following to pin the nixpkgs to make a project reproducible (with https://github.com/nmattia/niv):

```
{
  nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
, compiler ? "default"
, doBenchmark ? false
, sources ? import ./nix/sources.nix
}:

let

  niv = import sources.nixpkgs {
    overlays = [
      (_ : _ : { niv = import sources.niv {}; })
    ] ;
    config = {};
  };
  inherit (niv) pkgs;
...
```

With the above, I can `nix-build` successfully, though I'm not 100% sure it's using `niv` to pin the packages as intended.

**None the less, I'm now trying reference a github project - but I run into an error (`...called without required argument...`)?**

My attempt:

After running `niv add ...`:

```
nix-shell
error: 'f' at /home/chris/fromLaptopt/usbflash/Haskell/UraniumZuluGooseberry/shell.nix:18:7 called without required argument 'platinumpitanga', at /nix/store/j6spkp2a2sqd65db1sj9zzpgrfnkrwrp-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:87:27
```

---

Here is the entire shell.nix I'm using. Please note I do realize I'll still need to 'override' the Haskell / GHC package - please ignore this - I'm just hoping I need to figure out how to reference the external github package for now.

```
{
  nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
, compiler ? "default"
, doBenchmark ? false
, sources ? import ./nix/sources.nix
}:

let

  niv = import sources.nixpkgs {
    overlays = [
      (_ : _ : { niv = import sources.niv {}; })
    ] ;
    config = {};
  };
  inherit (niv) pkgs;

  f = { mkDerivation, aeson, base, bytestring, containers, hpack
      , influxdb, lens, platinumpitanga, pretty-simple, split, stdenv
      , stm, string-conversions, text, time, vector
      }:
      mkDerivation {
        pname = "UraniumZuluGooseberry";
        version = "0.1.0.0";
        src = ./.;
        isLibrary = false;
        isExecutable = true;
        libraryToolDepends = [ hpack ];
        executableHaskellDepends = [
          aeson base bytestring containers influxdb lens platinumpitanga
          pretty-simple split stm string-conversions text time vector
        ];
        preConfigure = "hpack";
        license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
      };

  haskellPackages = if compiler == "default"
                       then pkgs.haskellPackages
                       else pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler};

  variant = if doBenchmark then pkgs.haskell.lib.doBenchmark else pkgs.lib.id;

  drv = variant (haskellPackages.callPackage f {});

in

  if pkgs.lib.inNixShell then drv.env else drv
```

Comment: You seem to correctly import the sources into your `sources` variable, but you don't reference `sources` except for defining `niv` itself.

Comment: It seems like you'll need to create a package set that has both the UraniumZuluGooseberry and platinumpitanga packages. platinumpitanga is like turtle in https://github.com/Gabriel439/haskell-nix/blob/master/project1/README.md

Comment: Hmm isn't `inherit (niv) pkgs;` referencing `pkgs` from `niv`?

Comment: Regarding defining `platinumpitanga`. I'm aware of `fetchGit` and how to override a Haskell package. But according to the niv readme, it seems it can manage this dependency for me? I'm just not sure how to reference the package it manages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  niv = import sources.nixpkgs {
    overlays = [
      (_ : _ : {
        niv = import sources.niv {};
        platinumpitanga = niv.pkgs.haskellPackages.callCabal2nix "platinumpitanga"
          (sources.PlatinumPitanga) {} ;
      })
    ] ;
    config = {};
  };
  inherit (niv) pkgs;
```

I think the above is all that is needed (I've managed to go further with the nix-build at least).

Essentially `sources.PlatinumPitanga` - it's the name of the "repository".

Answer (score 0):

The actual "nix derivation" seems to be `sources.PlatinumPitanga` for example. However one still needs to `import sources.PlatinumPitanga {}` to use it (instantiate it?) as a "package".